openpyxl: '@' is inserted in front of =image() Excel function
I'm trying to insert the Excel formula =image(AC2) into cell C2 of my workbook using openpyxl, knowing the value in cell AC2 is a long text of the original URL of an image. The expected result is that=image(AC2) works as if you entered it manually in the Excel workbook in cell C2 (I tried and it works fine).
I know the Excel function =IMAGE() is not known by openpyxl.
>>> from openpyxl.utils import FORMULAE
>>> "IMAGE" in FORMULAE
False

So I tried the following scripts with the following results:
Script 1
    for row in range(2, worksheet.max_row + 1):
        imgUrl_cell_reference = f"{get_column_letter(imgUrl_column_index)}{row}"
        formula = f'=IMAGE({imgUrl_cell_reference})'
        worksheet.cell(row=row, column=post_overview_column_index).value = formula

Result: =@IMAGE(AC2) in the cell C2
Script 2
    for row in range(2, worksheet.max_row + 1):
        imgUrl_cell_reference = f"{get_column_letter(imgUrl_column_index)}{row}"
        formula = '=_xlfn.IMAGE({imgUrl_cell_reference})'
        worksheet.cell(row=row, column=post_overview_column_index).value = formula

Result: An error message when I try to open the Excel file: Excel file error message
Script 3
    for row in range(2, worksheet.max_row + 1):
        imgUrl_cell_reference = f"{get_column_letter(imgUrl_column_index)}{row}"
        formula = '=_xludf.IMAGE({imgUrl_cell_reference})'
        worksheet.cell(row=row, column=post_overview_column_index).value = formula

Result: An error message when I try to open the Excel file: Excel file error message
I am using Python 3.11, openpyxl 3.1.2. and latest version of Excel in Microsoft 365.
Thanks in advance for your help.

I found the answer to my question actually! Hope that can help the community!
formula = f"=_xlfn.IMAGE({imgUrl_cell_reference})" worksheet.cell(row=row, column=post_overview_column_index).value = formula

You should be able to answer your own question rather than adding as a comment

I found the answer to my question actually! Hope that can help the community!
formula = f"=_xlfn.IMAGE({imgUrl_cell_reference})" worksheet.cell(row=row, column=post_overview_column_index).value = formula 

